# Checking the presence of zeros in the first 3 non NA elements by row in R

Tags: r, indexing, apply, zero

I´m trying to delete the rows in a data frame which contain zeros in the first 3 non NA elements.

As example:

```
> c <- matrix(c(NA,NA,4,5,0,7,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,8,9,10,0,4,5,0,NA,NA), ncol=5, nrow = 4, byrow=T)
> c
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA   NA    4    5    0
[2,]    7    0   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA    8    9   10    0
[4,]    4    5    0   NA   NA
```

I´m expecting to have an output such as:
TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE
in order to create the subset without the rows with zeros in the first 3 non NA elements.

Does anyone have a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `apply`.  Loop through the rows, subset the non-NA elements, check whether 0 is in it

```
apply(c, 1, function(x) 0 %in% x[!is.na(x)][1:3])
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```